# Plotting data on time (date) axis

Tags: matlab, date, matlab-figure

I have data like this:

```
22.10.1980. 100  
25.10.1980. 120  
26.10.1980.  12
```

(only much more of it, and for each date, several independent measurements on the right).

Now, this is probably trivial, but I've never done anything like it in MATLAB, and am having problems finding similar examples online. I need to plot the data on a time/showing dates axis (x axis), with all dates inside (so, 23. and 24. as well ... for which I don't have measurements).

How can I get dates to show up on a plot axis?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems like it might be the best to use `datetick`.

Usage: `datetick('x')` or `datetick('x', dateformat)` with the available formats as explained in the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html).

Comment: This is outdated. Now you should use datetime http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/plot-dates-and-durations.html

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data file has the format given above, you could use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.de/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) to read the data:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','rt');
C = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %d','Delimiter','.','CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fid);
```

The first cell of `C` will contain an N-by-3 cell array of strings (the parts of the date) and the second cell of `C` will contain an N-by-1 vector of the data measurements. You can create a date number for each measurement by first concatenating the 3 smaller strings into one date string and then using the [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) function:

```
t = datenum(strcat(C{1}(:,3),'-',C{1}(:,2),'-',C{1}(:,1)));
data = C{2};
```

Once you have a vector of date numbers `t` to go with your vector of measurements `data`, you can then plot them:

```
plot(t,data,'*');  %# Plot the points as asterisks
```

Now, you can change the x-axis labels to show the actual dates. One option is to use the function [`datetick`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html), an easy and elegant solution given in [steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038339/plotting-data-on-time-date-axis-in-matlab/2038421#2038421). Another option is to use the function [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html) to create the labels yourself, then modify the [`XTick`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#XTick) and [`XTickLabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#XTickLabel) properties of the current axes:

```
xpts = min(t):max(t);  %# Make a full vector, filling in missing dates
set(gca,'XTick',xpts,'XTickLabel',datestr(xpts));  %# Set axes properties
```

---

**NOTE:** Whichever option you choose for changing the x-axis labels to date strings, you may run into trouble with the labels overlapping each other if the tick marks are too close together. You could fix this by reducing or repositioning the tick marks along the x-axis (by changing the [`XTick`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#XTick) property) or by adjusting the axes [`FontSize`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#FontSize) property. If you wanted to rotate the labels to make them fit, you would have to erase the labels and create new rotated [text objects](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) for them. The following submission on [The MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) does just that:

- [Rotate Tick Label](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722) by [Andrew Bliss](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/20418)

Answer (score 3):

With datenum you can convert any string date into numerical format based on the date format symbols (see help datestr).

For example all this leads to the same numerical date representation:

`datenum('15/05/2009 21:22','dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM');

datenum('15.05.2009 21:22','dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM');

datenum('21-22 15.05.2009','HH-MM dd.mm.yyyy');

datenum('21-22 05/15.2009','HH-MM mm/dd.yyyy');

...`

The nice thing is that you can pass cell array (output from textscan) or char array directly to datenum and it will output numeric date array.

Answer (score 2):

Datetick is a good option, as well as datetick2, which can be found here: [MATLAB Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20422-datetick-with-zooming-panning-and-subplots)

Datetick2 allows panning and zooming, with adjustments to the time labels, depending on how far you're zoomed in.

I'm not sure about the dd.mm.yyyy format - you could use regexp or strrep to change the decimals to dashes if neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datenum](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) to convert the dates to a numbers, and plot the data as usual. lets say you put your dates vector in the variable called x. 
Now, you can use

```
set(gca, 'xtick',x(1:10:end));
set(gca, 'xticklabel',datestr(x(1:10:end));
```

to set the ticks on the x axis.